# JMeter bzm - Parallel Controller class java.util.IdentityHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.HashMap exception

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using `jmeter 5.6.2` and Java
java version `17.0.8` 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)

After adding bzm - Parallel Controller to my thread group I faced this exception:

```
ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'bzm - Parallel Controller'.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.IdentityHashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.HashMap (java.util.IdentityHashMap and java.util.HashMap are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.cloneTestCompiler(JMeterThreadParallel.java:45) ~[jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.copyCompilerFromParent(JMeterThreadParallel.java:36) ~[jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.<init>(JMeterThreadParallel.java:26) ~[jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.ParallelSampler.sample(ParallelSampler.java:71) ~[jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME57r.png)

Any ideas how to fix this?

thanks

Tried different java versions but this didn't help.

Comment: Please, format your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there were [some breaking changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) in [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) hence [Parallel Controller 0.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.blazemeter/jmeter-parallel/0.11) can work only with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) or lower.

You will need to downgrade your JMeter version.

Alternatively there is a [workaround](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/pull/94#issuecomment-1647537976) in this ticket